# How can I stabilize several of my YouTube videos at once?

Tags: youtube

I uploaded 100 .mp4 video files on YouTube. I now want to stabilize all of them using the [YouTube video stabilizer feature](https://youtu.be/TcwE9g1-Fr8). Is there any way I can stabilize  all of them at once?

I tried searching the question on Google, I read the YouTube official documentation and I look around in YouTube studio, but couldn't find the answer.

This question might be relevant to others as stabilizing videos is useful from time to time.

Comment: This question has being asking three times before [1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/55442/), [2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/136912/), [3](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/149227/). so, for it to be given a fourth opportunity for answering, it needs to have considerably more details included, like what the asker has done to try and answer it themselves.

Comment: @Rubén I've already added more details.